# Google Auth with Android as client side and node js as server

Tags: android, node.js, jwt, google-authentication, passport-google-oauth

I have searched many links but didn't find any tutorial about :
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth

I want to configure my backend server for google authentication

my android code:

```
public class SignInActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;


private int RC_SIGN_IN = 101;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_in);


    SignInButton signInButton = findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
    signInButton.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_STANDARD);

    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

    mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);


    //Shared Preferences Editor
    editor = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit();

    // Callback registration

    signInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
            startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);

        }
    });

}
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        // The Task returned from this call is always completed, no need to attach
        // a listener.
        Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
        handleSignInResult(task);
    }
}
private void handleSignInResult(Task<GoogleSignInAccount> completedTask) {
    try {
        GoogleSignInAccount account = completedTask.getResult(ApiException.class);
        String idToken = account.getIdToken();




        // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.

    } catch (ApiException e) {
        // The ApiException status code indicates the detailed failure reason.
        // Please refer to the GoogleSignInStatusCodes class reference for more information.

    }
}}
```

How to convert google idToken into jwt token as facebook sign in in my node js app:

my node js Authentication.je file:

```
var passport = require('passport');

var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

var User = require('./models/user');

var JwtStrategy = require('passport-jwt').Strategy;

var ExtractJwt = require('passport-jwt').ExtractJwt;

var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

var FacebookTokenStrategy = require('passport-facebook-token');

var config = require('./config');

exports.local = passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()));

passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());

passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());

exports.getToken = function(user) {
    return jwt.sign(user,config.secretKey,
    {expiresIn:3600});
};

var opts = {};

opts.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken();

opts.secretOrKey = config.secretKey;

exports.jwtPassport = passport.use(new JwtStrategy(opts,
    (jwt_payload,done) => {
        console.log("JWT payload: ",jwt_payload);
        User.findOne({_id: jwt_payload._id},(err,user) => {
            if(err) {
                return done(err,false);
            } else if (user) {
                return done(null,user);
            } else {
                return done(null,false);
            }
        });
    }));


    exports.verifyAdmin = (req,res,next) => {
        if(req.user.admin){
            next();
        }else{
            err = new Error('You are not authorized to perform this operation!');
            err.status = 403;
            next(err);           
        }
};


exports.verifyUser = passport.authenticate('jwt',{session : false});

exports.facebookPassport = passport.use
(new FacebookTokenStrategy({
    clientID : config.facebook.clientId,
    clientSecret : config.facebook.clientSecret

},(accessToken, refreshToken ,profile, done) => {
    console.log(accessToken);
    User.findOne({facebookId : profile.id},(err,user) => {
    if(err){
        return done(err,false);
    }
    if(!err && user!=null){
        return done(null,user);
    }else{
        user = new User({username : profile.displayName});
        user.facebookId = profile.id;
        user.firstname = profile.name.givenName;
        user.lastname = profile.name.familyName;
        user.save((err,user) => {
            if(err)
            return done(err,false);
            else
            return done(null,user);
        });   
    }
});
}));
```

Links I have visited :
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth

https://github.com/google/google-auth-library-nodejs

https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-auth-library

Comment: Did you manage to make it work?